Unable to download pictures with Python
I want to download four pictures from four Urls. Sometimes I manage to download properly two of them, sometimes one and sometimes none of them. The remaining pictures are downloaded but in a invalid format.
What am I doing wrong? The code is relatively simple, I have no idea which are the causes of this problem.
Thank you for your suggestions!
This is my code:
import requests
import os
from requests.exceptions import RequestException

urls ={'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/c/c0/2_%E2%82%AC_commemorativo_Italia_2004.png',
       'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/d/db/2_%E2%82%AC_commemorativo_Austria_2005.png',
       'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/b/b4/2_%E2%82%AC_commemorativo_Finlandia_2004.jpg',
       'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/e/ed/2_%E2%82%AC_commemorativo_Belgio_2005.jpg'
}

def scarica(urlImmagini):
    folder = 'Coins'
    os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)
    
    for indice, urlImmagine in enumerate(urlImmagini, start =1):
        try:
            img_data = requests.get(urlImmagine, allow_redirects=True).content
            ext = urlImmagine.split('.')[-1].lower()
            nome = f"foto_{indice}.{ext}"
            nomeConDir = os.path.join(folder,nome)
            with open(nomeConDir, 'wb') as handler:
                handler.write(img_data)
        except RequestException as e:
            print(f"Errore durante il download dell'immagine {UrlImmagine}: {e}")

def main():
    
    scarica(urls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Thanks! This code seems to work even without specifying the request header..

It's unclear why your code might be behaving in the manner you describe.
Best practice (IMHO) when downloading web content is to stream the data.
This code might offer a more robust solution:
import requests
from pathlib import Path

CHUNK = 4 * 1_024

urls = [
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/c/c0/2_%E2%82%AC_commemorativo_Italia_2004.png",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/d/db/2_%E2%82%AC_commemorativo_Austria_2005.png",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/b/b4/2_%E2%82%AC_commemorativo_Finlandia_2004.jpg",
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/e/ed/2_%E2%82%AC_commemorativo_Belgio_2005.jpg",
]

(folder := Path("Coins")).mkdir(exist_ok=True)

with requests.Session() as session:
    ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_7_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.4.1 Safari/605.1.15"
    session.headers.update({"User-Agent": ua})
    for i, url in enumerate(urls, 1):
        with session.get(url, stream=True) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            ext = response.url.split(".")[-1]
            filename = folder / Path(f"foto_{i}.{ext}")
            with filename.open("wb") as image:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK):
                    image.write(chunk)


Why it fails is revealed by the print in:
    r = requests.get(urlImmagine, allow_redirects=True)
    img_data=r.content
    print('Reason:',indice,r.reason)

Example run:
Reason: 1 Forbidden. Please comply with the User-Agent policy: https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy
Reason: 2 OK
Reason: 3 OK
Reason: 4 OK


Thanks! You discovered the cause of the error!

Note: If you find an answer useful then use the "upvote" button, to rate it and/or set the "green tick" for the one that you find most useful.
